# "Жуйте после каждой еды?"

Tags: стилистика

Правильно ли говорить "после каждой еды"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что так говорить нельзя. Еда — это не процесс, а предмет. Правильно будет сказать "после каждого приема пищи".

Comment: Согласна. Словосочетание "после каждой еды" не верно, правильно "после каждого приема пищи

Comment: Вот и мне тоже так кажется. "После каждого приема пищи" либо "Каждый раз после еды".

Рассмотрим, к примеру, слово "бег". Существительное, обозначающее действие. "После бега он обливался холодной водой" - звучит вполне нормально. Но "после каждого бега он обливался холодной водой" - мне лично режет слух.

Answer (score 3):

Вполне.

ЕДА, -ы; ж.  
~1. Приём пищи. За едой. Во время еды, после еды. За едой не разговаривают. Принялись за еду. Ему не до еды (нет желания или времени поесть).
~2. То, что едят; пища. Столы ломились от обилия еды. Еды в доме никакой! После жирной еды хочется пить.
(БТС, Кузнецов)

Именно "прием пищи" даётся как главное (первое) значение. Ну в отношении первого-главного можно поспорить, но такое значение точно есть.

...

Я вот чего подумал. Современно значение "еда = прием пищи" появилось с уходом в прошлое понятия "трапеза". А ведь вполне удачное было слово. Оно бы не путало.